Cannot access state in Redux store
I wrote a simple Redux code for my application, with two simple actions. One is for updating my City state and the other one is for reading the City state. I have two components, Nav.js and Results.js. I get my city name from Nav component and the new city name is passed to the store with 'Update' action. I need to get the newly updated city name in the Results.js from Nav.js. But for some reason I end up with the following error-

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'City') TypeError: Cannot
read properties of undefined (reading 'City')

My code in Store.js-

import {createStore} from 'redux';
const Reducer=(state={City:'Dayton'},action)=>{
if(action.type==='Update')
{
    return 
    {
        City:action.New_City
    };
}

if(action.type==='Read')
{
    return 
    {
        state.City
    };
}

return state;

};
const Store=createStore(Reducer);
export default Store;

My code in Nav.js-

const [City_Text,Update_City_Text]=useState('Fairborn');
const dispatch=useDispatch();
const Update=()=>   {   dispatch({type:'Update',New_City:City_Text});   }


My code in Results.js-

const City1= useSelector(state=>state.City);

console.log(City1);



You can't have a newline after return. Javascript will automatically insert a semicolon, making it return;. Ie, you're implicitly returning undefined.
